# e2fsck not working

Tags: linux, filesystems, slitaz

I am using Linux slitaz on my machine.
I am able to see drives on the left side of the screen but when I click the drives it is giving the error cannot open the drive.

When I ran the `e2fsck` on that partition I am getting an error. I used the following command to run `e2fsck`:

```
e2fsck -y -f -V /dev/hda3
```

and this gives the following error:

```
error:
e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/hda3
Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

How can I resolve this?

when i did fdisk -l, i got this

```
Disk /dev/hda: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/hda1               1        2550    20482843+ 83 Linux
/dev/hda2            2551        2615      522112+ 82 Linux swap
/dev/hda3            2616        6439    30716280  83 Linux
/dev/hda4            6440        9729    26426925  83 Linux
```

Comment: Are you sure `/dev/hda3` is a partition that contains an ext2 filesystem?

Comment: @Shadur actually it is ext3 filesystem.

Comment: There's your first mistake, then.

Comment: @Shadur What mistake? `e2fsck` applies to ext2, ext3 and ext4. Mithunds: please copy-paste the output of `fdisk -l /dev/hda` and `tune2fs -l /dev/hda3`.

Comment: @Gilles sometimes Hard drive will not be detected.

Comment: Then your problem is not that e2fsck isn't working, but that your hard drive isn't working. Check the cable, and if that's not it, replace the hard drive by a working one.

Comment: @Gilles but some times it will be detected... when it is detected, i did fdisk -l and i got this..

Comment: @Gilles I have edited the post..

Comment: @Gilles and when i click on detected drive i am getting this error

Error <i>org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.Volume.UnknownFailure</i>

Comment: Concur with @Gilles -- almost certainly a hardware issue. Especially if it's only detected "sometimes".